# Prove $m=n$ of function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ which has an inverse

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$  have an inverse function ${F^{-1}}:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$
.If $F$  is differentiable at  $a\in R^{n}$  and $F^{-1}$  is differentiable at $b=F(a)\in R^{m}$, then show that $m=n$.

Hint: $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$, $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times m$ matrix.

I have considered $DF(a)$, inverse function theorem, etc. I just don't know how to use the hint to solve it. Can somebody teach me how to use that hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$tr(D(F^{-1} \cdot F)(a)) = tr(DF^{-1}(b) \cdot DF(a))
= tr(DF(a) \cdot DF^{-1}(b)) = tr(D(F\cdot F^{-1} )(b))$$
$$tr(D(F^{-1} \cdot F)(a)) = tr (I_n) = n$$
$$tr(D(F\cdot F^{-1} )(b)) = tr (I_m) = m$$
So $ n = m $

Comment: ...and here I thought I knew the easiest way to prove that all invertible matrices are square.

Answer (score 0):

The hint does not help me in any way (at least as long as $\rm tr$ denotes the trace of a matrix.

You can use the chain rule on

$$
(f \circ f^{-1}) (x) = x
$$

to conclude

$$
(Df)(f^{-1}(x)) \cdot (D f^{-1})(x) = I_m,
$$

where $I_m$ is the $m$-dimensional identity matrix.

Do the same for the converse "order" of $f$, $f^{-1}$. Why does this help you?